# why my remote server not able to connect to postgres instance on another Django server?

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I have two Ubuntu servers A and B.

- Initially I had Django, postgres, celery on single server A. Everything was working fine.
- Now A has Django, postgres, and B has celery and Django project installed.
- DB migrations are done on A, and database connectivity is proper on A. This I can say that because when I am trying to start the celery server on server A, I am able to successfully launch the celery through the command prompt. No problem.
- As per the requirements, I have to only run Django and postgres on server A, and Celery on server B.
- Since I am using the same Django server settings on server B that I have in A, so the Django settings.py has the same DB connectivity settings as shown below. i.e. the DB settings are same on A and B

  ```
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
          'NAME': 'xyz',
          'USER': 'smthing',
          'PASSWORD': 'smthing',
          'HOST': 'some_IP',
          'PORT': '5432',
      }
  }
  ```
- To see if the postgres is running or not on server A. I executed the service command

$ service postgresql status

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-06-10 10:57:11 IST; 1 weeks 4 days ago
 Main PID: 1276 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

- To see if the postgres is listing on 5432, I executed netstat command:

  ```
  $ netstat -nl | grep postgres

  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17357    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
  ```

If all these are happening, then why server B is throwing error as below when I am trying to start the celery?

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "server A" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

- One thing I noticed that when I tried to telnet server A from server B, I get failed output.

  ```
  telnet server A 5432
  [sudo] password for username:
  Trying server A...
  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
  ```

_ Also, please let me know if I need to have the username and password created on server B as well? i.e. the username and password which is present as a postgres user on server A.

Comment: By default, your Postgres installation is only available through the localhost. You'll need to somehow setup it (google) to be available from the outside. Alternatively, you can use a hosted solution like AWS RDS.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov, I do not have cloud env. They are on two different desktops.